# replacing more text strings with certain text strings in powershell

Tags: powershell

my code replace one text for another text well

```
$pathhh = "E:\times"
$searchWords = 'NEWYORK'
$replaceWord = 'CANCELED'

Foreach ($sw in $searchWords)
{
    Get-Childitem -Path $pathhh -Recurse | 
    Select-String -Pattern "$sw" | 
    Select Path,LineNumber,@{n='SearchWord';e={$sw}}
}

if (1 -eq 1) {
$files = Get-Childitem -Path $pathhh -File -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files) {
  $content = get-content -raw $file.PSPath
  # regex may have problems
  $content = $content -replace $searchWords,
    $replaceWord
  set-content $file.PSPath $content
}
```

}

but I need more different replacements like

replace NEWYORK with CANCELLED and replace LA with INFO and replace LONDON with DELAYED so more text replacements so like

```
$searchWords = 'NEWYORK,LA,LONDON'
$replaceWord = 'CANCELED,INFO,DELAYED'
```

but have no idea how to connect it all together thank you for your help!

Comment: take a look at hashtables - `Get-Help about_Hash_Tables`. they are REALLY good for lookup tables since they consist of a unique key and a value. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using two comma delimited strings as you are trying now, I would suggest creating a replacements map (Hashtable) to store the words to replace and their replacement strings in one easy to use structure.

Something like this:

```
$replacements = @{
    'NEWYORK' = 'CANCELLED'
    'LA'      = 'INFO'
    'LONDON'  = 'DELAYED'
}

$files = Get-Childitem -Path $pathhh -File -Recurse
foreach($file in $files) {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
    foreach ($item in $replacements.Keys) {
        $content = $content.Replace($item, $replacements[$item])
    }
    Set-Content -Path $file.FullName -Value $content
}
```

Comment: oh man thank you SO MUCH! was thinking after asking my question that better way would be to have a replacement list on more lines so every replacement is new line because there will be a lot of replacements and it will be way more friendly to read.. and then seeing your answer that it already contains that feature = thank you so much! :)